# How can I add an index to a field in my Active Record migration to make queries faster?

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, indexing, query-optimization

I used the following migration to create a table of dictionary words:

```
class CreateTerms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :terms do |t|
      t.string :word, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to add an 'index' but for some reason my queries are still slow. A server log:

```
Term Load (34.4ms)  SELECT "terms".* FROM "terms" WHERE (word LIKE ('launi%'))
```

When I lookup something by id its much faster:

```
Term Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "terms".* FROM "terms" WHERE "terms"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 143556]]
```

Am I adding the index correctly?

How can I get the first query down into the 1 ms range like 2nd one?

Comment: Start by looking at the explain output for the query. Also it's not unusual in general that an exact lookup on primary key be faster than a range lookup on a secondary key. For all I know that like% query could be returning 10000 rows

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is creating an index over the primary key and you include the column on which you are making a search. This would make querying the database really faster and 
easier.